# Using multiple and different strings for different environments

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this code from
https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/advanced-topics/basic-custom-validators/

```
function emailDomainValidator(control: FormControl) { (1)
  let email = control.value; (2)
  if (domain !== "domain1.com" && domain != "domain2.com" ){(3)
    let [_, domain] = email.split("@"); (4)
    if (domain !== "codecraft.tv") { (5)
      return {
        emailDomain: {
          parsedDomain: domain
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return null; (6)
}
```

I need to have different and multiple domains (devdomain1, devdomain2, testdomain1, testdomain2 etc.) for different environments.
Should we be defining those email domains in app.config or environment.ts and any example on how to use it with multiple domains?

I am using Angular CLI: 9.0.5

Answer (score 0):

you can add domain property in your environment files
**environment.ts**

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  domains: [`devdomain1`, `devdomain2`],
  emailDomain: `codecraft.tv`
}
```

**environment.prod.ts**

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  domains: [`proddomain1`, `proddomain2`],
  emailDomain: `codecraft.tv`
}
```

and do this in your validation function

```
import { environment } from './environments/environment';  // maybe you will need to correct the path


function emailDomainValidator(control: FormControl) { (1)
  let email = control.value; (2)
  const hasDomain = environment.domains.find(i => {i === domain})
  if (!hasDomain){(3)
    let [_, domain] = email.split("@"); (4)
    if (domain !== environment.emailDomain) { (5)
      return {
        emailDomain: {
          parsedDomain: domain
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return null; (6)
}
```

Comment: thanks @Ashot. What is domains and emailDomain? When I meant domains i meant gmail.com, yahoo.com in email addresses. And also whats domain in i === domain?

Comment: I did the changes depends on existing logic from your question

Comment: `environment. domains` can be the array where can be place `['gmail.com', 'yahoo.com']`

Comment: you have another condition `domain !== "codecraft.tv"` I just defined environment property for  `codecraft.tv`, so you can have it depends on the environment too if needed,